# i'm stuck on show bounding box. these error (cv2.rectangle(img(x1,y1), (x2,y2), (0,255,0),2) TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable )

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, face-recognition, bounding-box, drawrectangle

> these are the code that's i try

```
y1,x1,y2,x2 = faceLoc
y1, x1, y2, x2 =  y1*4,x1*4,y2*4,x2*4
cv2.rectangle(img(x1,y1), (x2,y2), (0,255,0),2)
```

Comment: Please provide more info about your code (e.g. what is `faceLoc`? What is `img`) and more detail about what you want to achieve. Also, please consider rename your question to something more title-like. Your current title is more suitable for the body of your question. Finally, please provide a full trace of your error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a comma after "img":

```
cv2.rectangle(img, (x1,y1), (x2,y2), (0,255,0),2)
```